# Multiple stocks portfolio return with rebalancing

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

So I have a portfolio composition (some shares included in the portfolio), and at specific dates I need to rebalance -that means the composition of the portfolio changes.
Dataframe includes columns ['Names'; 'Date_rebalancing'; 'Weights']

Then I have another big dataframe with daily return of all possible stocks.
I need to extract the portfolio return daily.

So when the rebalancing date happens portfolio_return_next_day is sumproduct(weights; returns_only_for_those_companies). Daily return is computed.

```
stock_return=prices.apply(lambda x: x/x.shift(1)-1)
```

I expect a list of daily portfolio returns

Comment: welcome to StackOveflow, please follow the guidelines and produce a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide more information in your next question, as mentioned by @Yuca

Answer (score 0):

On your big dataframe, you need to filter so that it matches your portfolio. So use [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df_select = df_big.loc[df_big['name'].isin.[df_port['name'],:]
```

df_select is now a dataframe with just your stock daily values. To get daily returns, there is a built in function [pct_return()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html). (# defaults to one period)

Let's say your column of closing prices is called 'Close'. Then create a new columns from the daily returns.

```
df_select['return'] = df['Close'].pct_return()
```

This will give you the dataframe with your stocks and percent return daily values.

Answer (score 0):

`df_unique_dates` are the dates where the rebalancing should take place. I already done the returns for each stock in `stock_return`but at each rebalancing date I have to select only those stocks that appear in portfolio `list_stocks`

```
    for i in range(len(df_unique_dates)):
    list_stocks=dataset.Name.loc[df_unique_dates[i]]
    for j in range(len(stock_return)):
        if stock_return.index[j]>df_unique_dates[i] and stock_return.index[j]<=df_unique_dates[i+1]:
             stock_return['portfolio']=0.1*stock_return[list_stocks].sum(axis=1)
stock_return
```